# replace text from docx using Python

Tags: python, csv, docx

I have a little side project I'm doing at work to help me with the "manual" labor of creating welcome documents for employees.

What I'm trying to do is:
1) Extract cell contents from a CSV file (username, first name, password)
2) Take cell contents and replace the strings [FirstName], [Username] and [Password] in the DOCX file.

This is the code:

```
""" Dependencies """
import csv
import numpy as np
import re
import shutil
import docx
#import fileinput

""" Open CSV and add usernames to list """
with open('UploadUsers.csv', 'rU') as csvfile:
    readCSV = np.loadtxt(csvfile, delimiter=',', skiprows=1, dtype = 'str')
    first_names = []
    usernames = []
    passwords = []

for row in readCSV:
    username = row[1]
    first_name = row[2]
    password = row[5]

    usernames.append(username)
    first_names.append(first_name)
    passwords.append(password)

for username in usernames:

    doc = "Free_Tracking_Manager_US.docx"
    doc_copy = "Free_Tracking_Manager_US.docx."+username+".docx"

    """ Make file copies """
    shutil.copy(doc, doc_copy)

    """ Make changes to first name, username and password """

    document = docx.Document(doc_copy)

    for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if '[FirstName]' in paragraph.text:
            print(first_name)
        if '[Username]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(username)
        if '[Password]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(password)

    """ Save document """
    document.save(doc_copy)
```

The script runs without errors, it makes copies of the documents but doesn't replace the strings. Not sure where the issue is...

UPDATE:

made the changes Abass suggested. I replaced:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if '[FirstName]' in paragraph.text:
            print(first_name)
        if '[Username]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(username)
        if '[Password]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(password)
```

with:

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if '[FirstName]' in paragraph.text:
            print(first_name)
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('[FirstName]',first_name)
        if '[Username]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(username)
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('[Username]',username)
        if '[Password]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(password)
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('[Password]',username)
```

Still doesn't work...

Answer (score 1):

IIUC You are not replacing the keyword strings after checking for their presence:

Do this change and it shall have the strings replaced.

```
for paragraph in document.paragraphs:
        if '[FirstName]' in paragraph.text:
            print(first_name)
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('[FirstName]',first_name)
        if '[Username]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(username)
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('[Username]',username)
        if '[Password]'  in paragraph.text:
            print(password)
            paragraph.text = paragraph.text.replace('[Password]',username)
```

Comment: Thanks, still not working... it makes the file copies but doesn't change content in the docx.

Comment: Please update your question with what changes you have made.

Comment: Done! Let me know what else needs to be done for it to work!